# how to vectorize for loops like the one mentioned below in numpy?

Tags: numpy, vectorization

How to vectorise the following code ? I have already looked at broadcasting but I am not able to figure out a way to vectorize the following code:

```
for k in range(m):
    b[k] = b[k,:] + c[k]
```

where `b` is a (2,3,4) size array and `c` is a (1,2) size array and `m` is some fixed integer??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code it seems `c` is a `1D` array. Now, to add the elements of `c` along the first axis of `b`, you need make `c` a `3D` array by adding two singleton dimensions (or new axes in NumPy terminology) at `axes=(1,2)` with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and then perform the much needed addition. This will bring in the vectorized [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) into play. So, the implementation would be -

```
b += c[:,None,None]
```

If `c` were really `(1,2)` shaped array, then the solution would be -

```
b += c.T[:,None]
```